# Why borel set over complex is the same as real plane?

Tags: real-analysis, borel-sets

Why borel set $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{C} = \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^2}$

Comment: The structures $\Bbb C$, $\Bbb R$, $\mathscr{E}^2(\Bbb R)$ (the euclidean plane), $\Bbb S^2(\Bbb R)$ (the Riemann sphere), despite being aimed at describing the same object, *are not completely equivalent each other in every aspect* (otherwise they would be useless). Said that, you question would be interesting if only you provide more context: where did you encountered this problem and why are you interested in it? Did you tried to approach it and, if you did, why did your approach fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(x,y) \to x+iy$ is a homeomorphism from $\mathbb R^{2}$ onto $\mathbb C$. Any homeomorphism preserves open sets, hence also Borel sets.

Comment: Thank you, by the way can you have a look at this question:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3394526/borel-measure-on-the-real-line